# Motherboard and CPU: what and how to choose

Tags: motherboard

I'm trying to assemble my private home server. I'm searching about a new motherboard and CPU, but I'm stuck because I don't know what, specifically, to check and which components are important. For motherboard, I know I have to check socket type. For CPU, it's important to check about cores and frequency, but also size of first and second level cache storage. I know also it's wrong to do an arithmetic sum of cores and freq, because it is not the real value. Can someone explain the most important feature of motherboard and CPU?

I prefer a better motherboard without graphic included, which is always expensive.

Comment: I hate to say but its terribly vague. What sort of home server? What kind of budget? Do you need a ton of processing power? storage?

Comment: It's private for family. I need to ssh, apache webserver with mysql, ftp. It's very small. Budget aroubd 100 euro for both. I know it's really low but I don't need a graphic board included and a simple quad core at 2.5 I think is enough. Anyway, about motherboards and cpus, what should I usually check to compare?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general-advice type question, which are no longer part of our scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm so what you are looking for is something I had in mind as well. keep in mind mine was supposed to serve as a NAS and a Plex server so might be not exactly what you want. So here is my list:

MB: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157390
CPU: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117374
Case(any mini ITX rated case will do): http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117374

PS: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817256097
Memory (8GB is more than enough): [http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148545&cm_re=DDR3-*-20-148-545-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148545&cm_re=DDR3-_-20-148-545-_-Product)

any drive you think is good for you.

So u don't actually need a lot of processing power. The trick is to understand what you will be using most. Mysql usually only runs on 1 thread, same as SSH. I seriously doubt u will stress the Pentium CPU. if you need more power then you should consider some other alternative. (But seriously, unless you are going to serve content to 20 users at the same time, you should be fine)

Thats just my 2 cents.

The mother board does not have IPMI!

if you want to be able to control the board without a monitor or keyboard you will need IPMI (when SSH is offline. Ex: when you are in BIOS or something like that).

So this MB looks ok: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157466

Comment: First of all, thank you. You got exactly the point. I thought also about NAS server, as you did. Some questions: I know intel is better than AMD, but why not choose a quadcore AMD for the same price of pentium? As you said, probably this equipment would be a great for 5 users. I'll take a look on the net for prices. I got also an unused saphire hd5750. For a lower price/quality, what equip would you check? Thanks again sir

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli So my rule of thumb is: Use Intel for almost everything. Use AMD if u have a specific software package or application in mind that runs better on AMD (Think MS Excel). Two things push me toward Intel: 1. (This is my opinion only) It is more future proof, you can upgrade more stuff than AMD (I might be wrong) 2. Uses less power and as a result less heat. Less heat = less noise. Less power use = less money spent over time.

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli For the GPU im not sure why you would want to use it. Unless u want to transcode movies using the GPU on this server you should be fine without it. Also if you want to install it anyway you will need a 450W or more PS (I would say 500W cause PS at the lower price ranges are not very efficient and you might have issues). Also the fan on the GPU might add too much noise. Your choice though:)

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli I dont know if i would go with anything cheaper. The only place i would suggest saving is: Get less RAM. You should be able to run everything with 4Gb (no promises on performance). Get a cheaper PS/ a used PS. Instead of a SSD get a HDD something smaller (bad idea if u want to host movies on it). The MB and CPU are already pretty cheap and if you go lower you might run into quality issues for the MB or the CPU might be too slow. Find a used Case or get a cheaper one.

Comment: Sorry for other questions: MB got integrated also graphic board. Do you know a good MB without graphic board but only the socket in order to use my saphire? Maybe without graph board I can get at the same price a better MB

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli You can still use your Saphire without any issues. in your price range every CPU will come with an IGP (integrated Graphics Processor) its not the MB that has the graphics its the CPU. All the sockets that would be in your price range have IGPs. The ones that dont are: LGA2011 and LGA2011v3 (there might be 1 or 2 more) They are very expensive. The cheapest CPU for LGA2011v3 is: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117402

Comment: I always thouth MB got included graphic board, but I read that since a while graphic is integrated in CPU, exactly as you said. Serial port on MB doesn't mean integrated card. Thank you again

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli Glad I could help! Just a warning: the MB i suggested does not have a serial port. The black port is a VGA port of a screen. Just FYI :)

Comment: Yes I saw. I don't think that a serial port should be so usefull... anyway there are also USB to serial port adapter :)